# Migrations can be unilaterally rejected by OP under certain conditions

Tags: bug, migration, moderator-tools, migration-rejection, self-delete

One of our users [posted a meta question on main](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/18808/revisions), so one of our mods migrated it to our meta site.

The interesting thing is that the user (owning an account on both meta and main by default), deleted his questions from meta. The result was the migration being cancelled, and the post ending up back on main (although closed with an "Off-topic" reason).

As immediate reaction, I migrated again and instructed the user to not delete his question, but that seems rather undesirable. Is it possible to exclude self-deletions from the migration rejection triggers?

I've tested it (by migrating a test question to Stack Overflow and deleting it from there) and it works even cross-site, as long as OP has an account on both sites. [Question on Stack Overflow (10k+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127490/testing-question-im-about-to-send-to-stack-overflow), [Question on Anime & Manga (2k+)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18811/testing-question-im-about-to-send-to-stack-overflow?noredirect=1)

Comment: Note to potential duplicate closers: the scenarios in the question I linked  in my answer and the one here are different, and this is a bug report while the other is a feature request, so I'm not going to vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

Per Shog9 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329133/377214):

> Special-casing author deletion here doesn't make sense to me; in cases where the question was indeed improperly migrated (as in, the author did not want it on the site where it was moved to), that's a pretty strong signal that it probably shouldn't have been migrated to begin with.

Also, I don't really see an issue here. The author may have honestly wanted to delete their question, and the origin question will still remain closed as off-topic after the migration gets rejected.

Given Shog's statement above, I think this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).