# How to flag/appeal against migration?

Tags: discussion, migration

A [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60506/readline-key-binding-function-to-repeat-last-searched-character) I posted was migrated by a moderator. The migration is wrong, perhaps because they didn't understand what it was about. How do I have them undo it?

Comment: You can flag your post for moderator attention and request to reject the migration. Alternatively the community can do so by close voting your question (I think you can start this as well) on emacs (but not as a duplicate). That will also lead to a reject. Your question will then be back and unlocked (but not open) on superuser. I've pinged the mod that was involved to look into this case.

Comment: I've reopened it on [su]. Mea culpa.

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35744/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73391/282094 and *sittin' pretty*: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247536/282094 ('cuz that's how you sit).

Answer (score 9):

Make a post on the per site meta on the original site explaining why the migration is incorrect. A moderator or two will review and we can reopen

Comment: I've reopened it on [su]. Mea culpa.

Comment: Well in general. :D. Posting to a site SU mods frequent PROBABLY helps too....